# Move all commits from a repository few months in the future

Tags: git, github

I have been looking at ways to move all previous commits in a repo to a later date. What I have found so far, is

```
`git filter-branch --env-filter 
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 119f9ecf58069b265ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0 ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi'`
```

But this is good if I am doing commit by commit. But is there a way to go through all the commits in a repo and move it a year later automatically instead of manually moving tons of commits?  Thank you.

EDIT: Just so that people don't down-vote this because it is bad practice etc, The reason I am doing this is to experiment with github's contribution chart/graph. This is a personal repo with a single user and no other contributors.

Comment: Curious, is there a _good reason_ for wanting to do this? _git_ is meant to be able to preserve your history. Should you every require any audit, this may compromize the integrity of the repo. Also know that you should never do this to a shared repository, only one that you own and manage / as after doing the force push to the remote, all other users of this repo will need to discard their working directories for your remote changes as they will now be incompatible / have different histories.

Comment: @MattClark : I certainly hope nobody uses the data metadata in git commits for audit purposes.  If you want to be able to do that, you need to sign either the relevant commits, or tags pointing to those commits, using a key that reasonably signifies an audit-worthy sign-off, because those values can be forged at will and changed any time a history rewrite is acceptable.  That said, the core question remains...

Comment: ... and the core question is, why would you want to do what Imprfectluck is asking.  I tend to suspect this question is based on some misconception about the effect of making such a change.

Comment: It is just a personal repository. This is not a production environment or anything. It is just an experiment i am doing with some the github contribution history chart. I fully understand the implications of doing this change. It is more an experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual admonitions of rewriting Git history apply here—your history will no longer match other copies of the repository, you must force push, but a force push is dangerous so you should `--force-push-with-lease` instead, etc. I will not question your motives here, since I think it should be well known that an unsigned Git history from a third-party is easily forged—you can trivially put whatever author you wish in your Git history, too. On a personal note, I am a bit unhappy that my personal habits and wake/sleep cycle can be scraped from my GitHub account, so I can understand the desire to scrub that data.

### How to do it

The hard part is manipulating the date correctly inside a shell script. The dates in the filter will be given with the format given by `date +'@%s %z'`, for example `@1536176083 -0400` might be one of the values. The problem is that calendrical arithmetic like “four months later” is not actually even possible at this point, because without knowing what the original time zone is, we have no way of knowing whether what the correct time zone offset will be four months later. In other words, Git simply *does not store the time zone* so if you want to preserve the time zone you have to reconstruct it, which is difficult.

What we *can* do, fairly easily, is just modify the timestamp by adding or subtracting a number of seconds, and then just putting everything in the local time zone. For example,

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
set $GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=@$((${1#@} + 24*60*60))
set $GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=@$((${1#@} + 24*60*60))
'
```

This will rewrite the commits to be 1 day after the original value (the `24*60*60` is the day). The time zone will be the local time zone for everything. If you want to preserve time zones of the original commits, that becomes a more difficult problem, which would probably require more manual intervention.

If you want to choose a specific time zone, you could set the `TZ` environment variable when you run Git.

Comment: I haven't checked if it works but damn that's actually brilliant.